# Test Observable that is piped and uses async pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have the following situation. I have an Observable, `myObservable$` initialized in `ngOnInit`. When that happens, the observable is tapped to copy the last value for other purposes. Aside from that, the observable is bound to something my html using the `async` pipe. How can I test that my tapped function is happening correctly, using jasmine karma?

html:

```
<input [ngModel]="myObservable$ |async">
```

ts:

```
ngOnInit():void {
    this.myObservable$ = this.service.getThings()
      .pipe(tap(value=>this.otherProperty=value))
}
```

I want to test, in this instance, that `this.otherProperty` actually has the value. How can I test this?

Comment: Mock your service call `this.service.getThings()` returning an Observable which produces some value - your test then asserts that `this.otherProperty` equals that value. There are a bunch of answered question on this I'll try to find one.

Comment: I tried that, using `const mySpy = spyOn (mockService, 'getThings').and.returnValue(of[4]))`. I get the error `Expected undefined to equal 4` in that case

Comment: my hunch is that it is related to the lack of subsription - since the subscription only happens due to the `async` pipe, which is not part of the test scope, how can it properly be tested?

Comment: You can subscribe manually inside test file myObservable$ and add expectation inside subscribe block

Comment: Right- you have to subscribe in your test -that emulates the expression's subscribe.

Comment: Thank you! Subscribing to myObservable$ in the test solved my issue

Comment: Thanks @Chellappanவ -- your comment helped me immensely today

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should install the spy onto `this.service.getThings()` method and returns a synchronous observable whose value is available immediately. Then, you can subscribe to it on the `ngOnInit` method of the component. At last, make an assertion for the `otherProperty` to check the value. For more info, see [Component with async service](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-with-async-service)

E.g. using `angular` v11+

`example.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ExampleService } from './example.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  template: '<input [ngModel]="myObservable$ |async">',
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  myObservable$: Observable<string>;
  otherProperty: string;
  constructor(private service: ExampleService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myObservable$ = this.service
      .getThings()
      .pipe(tap((value) => (this.otherProperty = value)));
  }
}
```

`example.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ExampleService {
  constructor() {}
  getThings() {
    return of('your real implementation');
  }
}
```

`example.component.spec.ts`:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { ExampleComponent } from './example.component';
import { ExampleService } from './example.service';

fdescribe('65479995', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ExampleComponent>;
  let component: ExampleComponent;
  let exampleServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<ExampleService>;
  beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
      exampleServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ExampleService', ['getThings']);
      exampleServiceSpy.getThings.and.returnValue(of('fake implementation'));

      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ExampleComponent],
        imports: [FormsModule],
        providers: [{ provide: ExampleService, useValue: exampleServiceSpy }],
      })
        .compileComponents()
        .then(() => {
          fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ExampleComponent);
          component = fixture.componentInstance;
        });
    })
  );
  it('should pass', () => {
    expect(component.otherProperty).toBeUndefined();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.otherProperty).toBe('fake implementation');
    expect(exampleServiceSpy.getThings).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
================================================================================
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
Chrome Headless 80.0.3987.87 (Mac OS 10.13.6): Executed 2 of 47 (skipped 45) SUCCESS (0.17 secs / 0.063 secs)
TOTAL: 2 SUCCESS
```

[image]